# Milo OPC Ua Subscription not operated at node's data change , only Interval

Tags: java, opc-ua, milo

this milo github
https://github.com/eclipse/milo

I use

```
ManagedSubscription subscription = ManagedSubscription.create(client);

subscription.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onDataReceived(List<ManagedDataItem> dataItems, List<DataValue> dataValues) {

   // I added data log code
}
});

ManagedDataItem dataItem = subscription.createDataItem(Identifiers.Server_ServerStatus_CurrentTime);
if (!dataItem.getStatusCode.isGood()) {
throw new RuntimeException("uh oh!")
}
```

and i attempt to change server's node data
but client data log is not appear

so I fixed listener

```
 subscription.addDataChangeListener((items, values) -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
                log.info(
                    "subscription value received: item={}, value={}",
                    items.get(i).getNodeId(), values.get(i).getValue()
                );
            }
        });
```

but subscription is running only interval time, not data changed time

what is problem?

Comment: DataValue{value=Variant{value=1000.0}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=0, javaDate=Mon Jan 01 09:00:00 KST 1601}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=132845349750036630, javaDate=Tue Dec 21 13:36:15 KST 2021}}

DataValue{value=Variant{value=1000.0}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=0, javaDate=Mon Jan 01 09:00:00 KST 1601}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=132845349770193000, javaDate=Tue Dec 21 13:36:17 KST 2021}}

Comment: This problem is occurred by ServerTime field change

if ServerTime is null, subscription normal work?
To Fixed ServerTime  null, do i have to fix server's source?

Comment: attention serverTime=DateTime{utcTime= ~~~)